# Set default selection for a spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I know this is probably a relativity simple question, but I seem to be overlooking the answer.

In my app, I have a spinner for the user to select the state that they live in.  Currently, the app will be focusing on a local audience so I would like to set the default selection to be the state that they live in.

I tried doing:

**registration_screen.xml**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinHomeState"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:entries="@array/state_list"
    android:prompt="@string/state_prompt"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>
```

**RegistrationScreen.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration_screen);

    Spinner HomeStateSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinHomeState);
    HomeStateSpinner.setSelection('9');
}
```

But the app crashes with the following logcat logs:

> 06-03 13:52:44.512
>   1736-1736/com.name.of.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.hollywoodcert.soupserver.hollywoodcert, PID: 1736
>       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 57, size is 50
>               at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>               at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:66)
>               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
>               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
>               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
>               at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:592)
>               at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:540)
>               at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:502)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
>               at android.widget.TableRow.onLayout(TableRow.java:123)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>               at android.widget.TableLayout.onLayout(TableLayout.java:448)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>               at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1468)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>               at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the android docs, the Spinner method `setSelection` receives either an `int` or `int` and `boolean` arguments.

In your code your calling `HomeStateSpinner.setSelection('9');` passing a `char` as argument. Another thing is that the `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown means that you're trying to access a position outside of the array set on the spinner.

My sugestion is first to try and call the method like so:

```
HomeStateSpinner.setSelection(9);
```

And if that doesn't work, try calling it with a lower value like:

```
HomeStateSpinner.setSelection(2);
```

Comment: Thank you!! Originally I was going to write the command like that, but at first Android Studio showed that it wasn't correct (red squiggly line).  Maybe I was just too quick.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String compareValue = "9";

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_layout, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        rooms.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        if (!compareValue.equals(null)) {
            int spinnerPostion = dataAdapter.getPosition(compareValue);
            HomeStateSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPostion);
            spinnerPostion = 0;
        }
```

if 9 is the string use above solution,else 9 is the index/position at which you want to set selected then just use:

```
HomeStateSpinner.setSelection(9);
```

This must solve your problem.